# I would like to know if there is anything wrong with my Actioncript Code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I`m creating an application to catalogue childrens books like the dewey decimal system but simpler.

The app works like this:

1. Input a number in the text box
2. Click on the button
3. If the number corresponds with a books associated with that number then the title of the book appears.

This is what the code looks like:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.text.*;

    public class U3A3_Livres extends MovieClip {

        private var monMessage:TextField=new TextField;
        private var maMiseEnForme:TextFormat=new TextFormat;

        public function U3A3_Livres():void {
            btnTitreLivre.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, titreLivre)
        }

        private function titreLivre(event:MouseEvent):void {
            maMiseEnForme.font="Arial";
            maMiseEnForme.size="12";
            maMiseEnForme.bold=false;
            maMiseEnForme.color=0x660000;
            maMiseEnForme.x=330;
            maMiseEnForme.y=320;

            monMessage.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            monMessage.border=false;
            monMessage.defaultTextFormat=maMiseEnForme;

            var number:int = int(txtNumber.text);

            // CONDITION UN (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 2.)
            if (number == 2)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Pinocchio";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION DEUX (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 5.)
            else if (number == 5)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Marie Chapdelaine";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION TROIS (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 7.)
            else if (number == 7)
            {
                nouvMessage = "L'Homme invisible";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION QUATRE (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 10.)
            else if (number == 10)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Contes fantastiques";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION CINQ (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 13.)
            else if (number == 13)
            {
                nouvMessage = "L'Assassin habite au 21";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION SIX (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 17.)
            else if (number == 17)
            {
                nouvMessage = "L'Agent secret";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION SEPT (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 22.)
            else if (number == 22)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Robinson Crusoe";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION HUIT (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 25.)
            else if (number == 25)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Les aventures d'Alice au pays des merveilles";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION NEUF (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 29.)
            else if (number == 29)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Voyage au centre de la terre";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION DIX (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 30.)
            else if (number == 30)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Famille suisse Robinson";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION ONZE (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 31.)
            else if (number == 31)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Trois mousquetaires";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION DOUZE (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 35.)
            else if (number == 35)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Aurélia";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION TREIZE (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 36.)
            else if (number == 36)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Les deux orphelines";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }

            // CONDITION QUATORZE (Vérifier si la personne a écrit le numéro 40.)
            else if (number == 40)
            {
                nouvMessage = "Le joueur";
                monMessage.text=nouvMessage;
                addChild(monMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify - are you asking for help finding any subtle bugs, or do you just want comments on coding style, etc?  If the latter, this would be a better question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Brian the aplication doesn`t work. I was wondering if the code had something to do with it or if its just the button that is faulty.

Comment: How does it fail?  Do you get an error message, or does it simply ignore your button click?  Or something else?  Have you gone through in debug mode to find where in your code the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of duplicated code.

To add a new book, you have to create a whole if/else-if block and add it to the existing ones. In terms of maintainability, this is wrong.

If you store your data in a data structure, you can get rid of all the duplicated code.